# Chrome "Sending request..." indefinitely

Tags: google-chrome

After some time browsing in Chrome (30 minutes on average, varies widely), it suddenly can't receive any data from the Internet whatsoever.

Trying to go to any address displays the "Sending request..." message indefinitely. This happens out of the blue, not after doing anything special. Other browsers continue to work perfectly.

Quitting and relaunching Chrome always solves the problem, but nothing else works.

This problem is really annoying; it has been that way for many versions, even the latest one as of now. Has anyone else experienced this problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using any Chrome add-ins/extensions? Are you behind/using a proxy? Do you use a program similar to SpeedBit Video Accelerator?

Comment: @Josh King Yes, I use Speedbit Video Accelerator, and I have some extensions including youtube video downloaders. It seems related to youtube or videos because just now I had the problem (stuck at "Waiting for www.youtube.com...") but other websites like google or wikipedia were working (usually doesn't happen that way).

I have disabled a few extensions but Video Accelerator is still on, will see if the problem persists.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, with no proxies and nothing like the video accelerator.  Firefox on the same machine loads the same page in one-second-or-less sorts of time; chrome is still hanging a minute later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close the Speedbit Video Accelerator program (force the process to close if you have to), you'll notice Chrome starts playing nice again. I'm not sure why Chrome has issue with it... but apparently it [does](http://www.moneytalksonline.com/2010/11/google-chrome-sending-request-problem-solve/).

Comment: Thanks, as you said the video accelerator process (called "service") also needs to be killed and then Chrome works again without even restarting it. If I relaunch video accelerator, the problem comes back very quickly even though chrome can't even use it anymore (the "accelerating" message isn't displayed, whereas it's displayed when playing from Firefox), very annoying.

Goodbye Video Accelerator then...

Comment: The article you linked is the worst I've ever read. To paraphrase: "this thing happens, to fix it I stop using a plugin"

Answer (score 2):

After several hours of trouble-shooting and several days of inconvenience, I've discovered that Speedbit is causing Chrome to pull up blank pages when surfing. It will load the page after going to the address, the only problem is that nothing shows.

It is my impression that Speedbit actually slowed the speed of online videos, rather than speeding them up. It may be that those with DSL are getting pretty good speed anyway and that this additional software creates more interruptions while playing than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the Chrome executable file
2. Select `Properties`
3. Select the `Security` tab
4. Make sure `Network Service` has `Full Control` permissions; if not, add them
5. Select `Apply` and `OK`. Now try it

Answer (score 0):

I had some odd intermittent problems with things not loading properly from cache a few days ago after a recent Chrome update. These were items that would have been cached before the update and included the CSS and JS from stackoverflow.com. It probably is not be the same thing, but if it helps, clearing the cache did it for me.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried that many times already, it didn't work. Some kind of cache related to Speedbit Video Accelerator (not the usual browser cache which can be deleted) seems to accumulate and cause problems when it's too big, so that after some time all hits to www.youtube.com (or other video site I suppose) stalls, although "waiting for cache" isn't displayed, just "waiting for www.youtube.com". Only restarting chrome works.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to offer my alternative solution in case anyone else stumbles here from Google and the other suggestions don't work.

I wasn't running any extensions or accelerators so it had to be something else. Turned out my computer was having trouble reaching the DNS servers which were on the other side of a VPN. On my PC when this happens I get no DNS. But I'm on a Mac today and it just waited for the primary DNS to time out before I guess it goes to an alternate source automatically, or something like that.

Since I didn't really need access to that DNS right now (and it is a weekend so the IT guy is out) I just switched my network adaptor's DNS to Google's servers and it resolved issue.